# ga.getAll() does not return all the trackers

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Using Google Tag Manager with 4 Analytics tags: 3 tags trigger on "Page View" while 1 tag triggers on "JavaScript error".

The tags per se work fine: if an `uncaught JavaScript error` happens, the event is fired properly and collected by Google Analytics.

## Goal

I would like to use that tag also to fire custom events to send to Analytics also those errors that are `caught`.

## Problem

The other 3 tags are available in my code when doing `ga.getAll()` or `ga.getByName()`. The fourth tag instead is not in the array. It becomes available `only after at least 1 uncaught exception is thrown`. This makes `getByName` unreliable in case the caught error happens before any uncaught error.

Is this a `ga` bug or the desired behavior ? Is there another way to achieve the error logging, maybe via `dataLayer` or a separate tag configured in a different way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trackers are created when the tag is fired, so this is expected behavior - ga.getByName() is not unreliable here, it just cannot return trackers that haven't been instantiated yet.